# How can i approach an object expression returned in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

```
fun personInfo(_name: String, _age: Int):Any {

    val person = object {
        val name = _name
        val age = _age
    }
    return person
}
fun main() {

   val result = personInfo("sam", 36)
    println(result.name) //error
    println(result.age) //error

}
```

why can't i use the " println(result.name)" and " println(result.age)"???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why can't i use the "`println(result.name)`" and "`println(result.age)`"???

Because you declared the return type of `fun personInfo` to be `Any`. An `object` expression does not have a named type so you can't refer to it unless you refer directly to the result of the expression, which you can only do if it's a top-level variable.

Kotlin doesn't feature structural types, instead you must declare a named interface with those properties:

```
interface PersonInfo {
    val name: String
    val age: Int
}

fun personInfo(_name: String, _age: Int) = object : PersonInfo {
    override val name = _name
    override val age = _age
}
```

However, I would consider this a very awkward idiom in Kotlin, a data class would be much more natural:

```
data class PersonInfo(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)

fun personInfo(_name: String, _age: Int) = PersonInfo(_name, _age)
```

You may just as well drop the `fun personInfo` and use the constructor directly.